# FtpWebRequest general question. How often is safe to make requests

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I have a general question about the `FtpWebRequest`.

I have 2 computers that calls the same server using those methods randomly to a server.

```js
Ftp.UploadFile
Ftp.DownloadFile
Ftp.ListDirectory
Ftp.DeleteFile
Ftp.MakeDirectory
```

Sometimes it can be alot of requests and what I am afraid of is if the server can get to many requests during a short period of time when requests are very much.

My question that I think is important. Should one limit the requests to for example 1 every second etc so there isn't a scenario where it can come 20 requests in one second?

What can we say about this. What is a good practise to use in general?

Comment: Look into mutexes

Comment: lock objects and mutexes I know about. But I refer to my question again :)